# Building construction effect

Tags: modifiers, particles, physics

I want to make a building construction  effects like this:
https://youtu.be/Ln2ZmgAaN1Y

[image]
[image]
[image]

I have tried it with geometry nodes but the results are unsatisfying and doesn't look as good as the reference.
Here is what i have done: https://youtu.be/i-tw-7n_XC8

my nodes are mostly transfering indexes from one geometry to another by using the sample nearest node and then set position.

and my most successful one are using cube as particles that all appear on frame 1, and "destroy" them using a forcefield, then reversing the video later.
Link: https://youtu.be/llGFrMYqbAg

i would like to explore my idea using the particles, but now i have a new problem. i cant make the particles to face the normal direction, causing the building to look blocky and unnatural

[image]

[image]

how do i "spawn" the particles facing the normal directions and also spawns it neatly, not randomly.
i tried messing with these, but i see no difference

[image]

if you guys have any other solution i would like to hear them too ! thankyou

Comment: Instead of arranging particles to construct a building, you want to just model your building, with a consideration for the insides of the building (normally you don't care about the insides, but because of the building transition you can see it), and then somehow embed an information to distinguish separate building blocks - e.g. divide the model into separate islands (and use *Mesh Island: Island Index* node), or separate objects (then in geonodes you would use a *Collection Info* node). Then just animate blocks flying off, and reverse the animation.

Comment: Previous attempt: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/296845/building-construction-effect

Comment: thankyou for the response, im very new to geo node, so i'm having a hard time understanding your comments, hahah sorry !

Comment: Please do not ask a question twice, instead try to clarify the concerns in your original question and have it reopened.

Comment: the stack exchange gives me 2 choice, "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. You can edit the question or post a new one." and i pick the post a new one

Answer (score 2):

You could use a classical physic method: Create your building with a cube and some *Array* modifiers on X, Y and Z, apply the modifiers and separate each cube as different objects, put their origin at their geometry, give them *Rigid Body*, create a *Force Field > Turbulence* with a high Strength and *Falloff > Shape >Sphere* and *Min Distance > 0*, *Max Distance > 3* or whatever value you need, keyframe the force field so that it moves down, cut off the *Gravity*, bake the simulation to keyframes if necessary:

[image]

Comment: I imagine you could reverse the gravity and turn the physics on the objects sequentially, so they don't fly off at once, then when reversing the simulation the objects would assemble as if they were falling down.

Comment: you can bake the simulation if you want to reverse the simulation

Comment: i tried this too, but now the building looks blocky and unnatural, because it is arrayed.

Comment: @FernaldyWiranata it's just an example, arrange the blocks however you want, they also don't need to all have the same shape.

Comment: You can move them a bit in Object mode: Object > Transform > Randomize Transform